# DolphinDB Java API: How to obtain the columns and types of a table if only the table name is known?

Tags: java, dolphindb

I have a table pt1, only know the table name. How can I obtain the fields and types via DolphinDB Java API? The problem is the table I'm querying is not created by me and only the table name is known.

I've learnt that DolphinDB's function `columnNames` can return the column names. But if I want to use this function, I will have to first create BasicTable. I'm stuck here.
Also tried `getClusterDFSDdatabases` and `getClusterDFSTables` but they didn't work when I want the retrieve the fields. Please advise if there is any applicable method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adopt Java run() method to call DolphinDB built-in functions.
The first argument of the run() method is the DolphinDB function name and the second is the function parameters.

Use loadTable to get BasicTable:

```
List<Entity> arguments1 = new ArrayList<Entity>(1);
BasicTable table1 = (BasicTable) conn.run("loadTable('dfs://testDatabase','pt')");
arguments1.add(table1);
BasicStringVector o1 = (BasicStringVector)conn.run("columnNames",arguments1);
System.out.println(o1.getString());
```